# Wrong Median Answer

Tags: java, arraylist, median

Problem: I'm having an issue with counting the median value of my arrayList

Background: So my ArrayList gets randomly generated values and i have to calculate median of it; i believe my median formula is fine yet i'm getting wrong median answers for 3 values in an ArrayList.

for like three values, it's giving the wrong median. E.G:
when the array list has the values:
193.5, 200.5, 239.8
then the program is simply taking the average of first two values and giving the answer instead of going for 200.5

```
public double getMedianB(){
    Collections.sort(myDataB);
    double middle = myDataB.size()/2;
    if (myDataB.size()%2 == 1) {
       middle = (myDataB.get(myDataB.size()/2) + myDataB.get(myDataB.size()/2 - 1))/2;
    } else {
        middle = myDataB.get(myDataB.size() / 2);
    }
    System.out.println("median:" + middle);
  return middle;
}
```

Comment: is this code supposed to be re-usable for any amount of values? either way, it seems to me the code does exactly what you coded it to do.

Comment: Notice that index starts of zero.

Comment: AFAIK shouldn't it be the other way around? I mean `if (myDataB.size() % 2 == 0) {do average of middle values}`? Because it's in the odd case that you have the median as perfectly middle value while when you have an even number of values you need to find a value between the two in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Median is calculated by

1. Arrange list in ascending order
2. If number of items in list are odd, then the middle number is the median
3. If number of items are even, then add the middle two numbers and divide it by two, this result will be the median

In your code you have conditions for even and odd switched, so correct one would be as below

```
if (myDataB.size()%2 == 0) {
   middle = (myDataB.get(myDataB.size()/2) + myDataB.get(myDataB.size()/2 + 1))/2;
} else {
    middle = myDataB.get(myDataB.size() / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should flip your conditions:

The below condition checks if the number of terms is odd. In that case, you just want the single middle value.

```
if (myDataB.size()%2 == 1) {
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the middle value, you simply need to fetch the middle value. rather in your example, you are calculating some average of the first two values.

Change code to:

```
Collections.sort(myDataB);
        double middle = myDataB.size()/2;
        if (myDataB.size()%2 == 1) {
           middle = (double)myDataB.get(myDataB.size()/2);
        } else {
            middle = (double) myDataB.get(myDataB.size() / 2);
        }
        System.out.println("median:" + middle);
```

Change else condition, whatever you want to perform there.